# Problem in solving a trancedental equation which is embedded in module

Tags: equation-solving, scoping

I have written a small program to compute the resonance frequency, for that I am solving a transcendental equation, which comes from the determinant of the matrix `Rarz`. The matrix is constructed by minimizing `Lg` which is the lagrangian of the whole system. But I am facing some error `The solution set contains a full-dimensional component; use Reduce for complete solution information.`. How to overcome this and achieve the desired roots.

```
Y = 2*^11;
ρ = 7850;
aa = 0.1*0.1;
Iyy = 0.1^4/12;
L1 = 4;
z[1] = 1.5;
z[2] = 3;

v1 = 833333. (4.05871 c[1]^2 - 3.78041 c[1] c[2] + 15.6649 c[2]^2 + 
     2.40944 c[1] c[3] - 31.1201 c[2] c[3] + 17.3741 c[3]^2 + 
     1.49046 c[1] c[4] + 5.57631 c[2] c[4] + 6.49524 c[3] c[4] + 
     26.2414 c[4]^2 - 6.93889*10^-15 c[1] c[5] - 34.5037 c[2] c[5] + 
     36.0273 c[3] c[5] - 5.71687 c[4] c[5] + 20.5472 c[5]^2 - 
     6.2727*10^-12 c[1] c[6] - 1.77359*10^-10 c[2] c[6] - 
     16.1834 c[3] c[6] - 76.3793 c[4] c[6] + 
     7.57401*10^-11 c[5] c[6] + 64.9394 c[6]^2 + 2.65403 c[1] c[7] + 
     11.0488 c[2] c[7] + 4.813*10^-10 c[3] c[7] + 54.4986 c[4] c[7] - 
     13.7664 c[5] c[7] - 80.9352 c[6] c[7] + 29.6808 c[7]^2 - 
     1.97407 c[1] c[8] + 0.857837 c[2] c[8] + 7.05203 c[3] c[8] - 
     0.02407 c[4] c[8] + 9.08301 c[5] c[8] + 37.0375 c[6] c[8] - 
     13.361 c[7] c[8] + 66.6515 c[8]^2);
t1 = 39.25 ω^2 (0.666667 c[1]^2 - 0.620954 c[1] c[2] + 
     0.656721 c[2]^2 + 0.395765 c[1] c[3] - 1.06372 c[2] c[3] + 
     0.643704 c[3]^2 + 0.245338 c[1] c[4] + 0.233928 c[2] c[4] + 
     0.24039 c[3] c[4] + 0.486999 c[4]^2 - 2.28333*10^-15 c[1] c[5] - 
     1.11949 c[2] c[5] + 1.16893 c[3] c[5] - 0.185756 c[4] c[5] + 
     0.666667 c[5]^2 + 6.18657*10^-13 c[1] c[6] - 
     5.15522*10^-12 c[2] c[6] - 0.166138 c[3] c[6] - 
     0.78423 c[4] c[6] + 2.89399*10^-13 c[5] c[6] + 0.666667 c[6]^2 + 
     0.43594 c[1] c[7] + 0.30259 c[2] c[7] - 
     3.87273*10^-12 c[3] c[7] + 0.931506 c[4] c[7] - 
     0.446659 c[5] c[7] - 0.830879 c[6] c[7] + 0.507267 c[7]^2 - 
     0.324153 c[1] c[8] + 0.0360136 c[2] c[8] + 0.261246 c[3] c[8] - 
     0.000415737 c[4] c[8] + 0.29466 c[5] c[8] + 0.380217 c[6] c[8] - 
     0.228325 c[7] c[8] + 0.416657 c[8]^2);

var1 = Table[c[i], {i, 1, 8}];

(*first bar*)
sd1 = Subdivide[0.001, 0.5, 300];
sd2 = Subdivide[0.55, 2, 300];
sd3 = Subdivide[2.2, 100, 300];
sd = Flatten[{sd1, sd2, sd3}];

γ = L1*sd;
fixedfree1 = 
  Table[Sin[((2*0 + 1)*π*x2)/(2*γ[[i]])], {i, 1, 
    Length[γ]}];
fixedfree2 = 
  Table[Sin[((2*1 + 1)*π*x2)/(2*γ[[i]])], {i, 1, 
    Length[γ]}];

U1 = Table[(Subscript[d, 1][1]*fixedfree1[[i]] + 
     Subscript[d, 1][2]*fixedfree1[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[γ]}];
U1x = Table[D[(U1[[i]]), {x2, 1}], {i, 1, Length[U1]}];

in3 = Table[Expand[(U1x[[i]])^2], {i, 1, Length[U1x]}];
in4 = Table[Expand[(U1[[i]])^2], {i, 1, Length[U1x]}];

var2 = {Subscript[d, 1][1], Subscript[d, 1][2]};
v2 = Table[
   0.5*Y*aa*(Integrate[in3[[i]], {x2, 0, γ[[i]]}]), {i, 1, 
    Length[γ]}];
t2 = Table[
   0.5*ρ*
    aa*ω^2*(Integrate[in4[[i]], {x2, 0, γ[[i]]}]), {i, 
    1, Length[γ]}];

(*second bar*)
U2 = U1 /. {Subscript[d, 1] -> Subscript[d, 2], x2 -> x3};
v3 = v2 /. Subscript[d, 1] -> Subscript[d, 2];
t3 = t2 /. Subscript[d, 1] -> Subscript[d, 2];
var3 = var2 /. Subscript[d, 1] -> Subscript[d, 2];

(*total energy*)
T = Table[Simplify[t1 + t2[[i]] + t3[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[t2]}];
V = Table[Simplify[v1 + v2[[i]] + v3[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[v2]}];

(*defining lagrangian*)
Lg = Table[((T[[i]] - 
       V[[i]]) + λ1*((0.408248 c[1] + 0.118904 c[2] - 
          1.01315*10^-11 c[3] - 2.95423*10^-11 c[4] - 0.220942 c[5] + 
          0.57735 c[6] - 2.7989*10^-11 c[7] - 
          2.05928*10^-11 c[8]) - (U1[[i]] /. 
          x2 -> γ[[i]])) + λ2*((-0.57735 c[1] - 
          9.55289*10^-12 c[2] + 0.300783 c[3] - 1.07327*10^-11 c[4] + 
          0.408248 c[5] - 2.12681*10^-15 c[6] - 0.20051 c[7] - 
          5.77511*10^-11 c[8]) - (U2[[i]] /. 
          x3 -> γ[[i]]))), {i, 1, Length[γ]}];

variables = Flatten[{var1, var2, var3, λ1, λ2}];

(* upto here every thing works,  from sol[j_] some problem is \
occuring*)

(*minimizing lagrangian and solving the determinant for roots*)
sol[j_] := 
  Module[{root}, 
   equations = 
    Table[D[Lg[[j]], {variables[[i]], 1}], {i, 1, Length[variables]}];
    Rarz = Normal@CoefficientArrays[equations, variables][[2]]; 
   P = Chop[Det[Rarz]]; s1 = NSolve[P == 0 && 0 < ω < 5000]; 
   s2 = ω /. s1; s3 = Surd[(ρ*aa*s2^2*L1^4)/(Y*Iyy), 4]; 
   s4 = s2/(2 π); root = s3; Return[root]];

nonbeta = Table[sol[i], {i, 1, Length[γ]}];
nonbeta1 = nonbeta[[All, 2]]

data1 = Transpose[{sd, nonbeta1}];
p[1] = ListLogLinearPlot[data1, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Thickness[0.006]}]
```

Comment: "Small"?  Scroll through the questions here and see how long it takes you to find even a single longer program.  Small??

Comment: Actually it is a part of the program. I tried to make it concise as much as possible. this is what I end up with

Comment: The determinant `P` for the matrix `Rarz` is identically (numerically?) zero, so `NSolve` only sees $0<\omega<5000$.

Comment: @acoustics:  Thanks for trying to provide a minimum-working-example.  Just don't call it "small."